# Uploading a photo with GPS location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, photo

Is there a way to pass the GPS coordinates where the photo was taken as location parameter to the FB Graph API photo upload ( https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos )?

FB announced a while ago they will add this feature to the photo objects. Actually they said the location can be added to every update and if I upload a photo through the FB web interface I can indeed define the location where a photo was taken. Now I want to pass this as a parameter to the photo upload from my mobile app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the photos endpoint only supports adding a Facebook Page as location for the Photo. The place field is just the Facebook Page ID.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Im not sure if you can post ACTUAL gps coordinates to the post - however</strike> 
You can specify a location object to the post. You can read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) for more information on creating a post and what parameters you can pass.  
The location parameter is called `place` :

> object containing id and name of Page associated with this location,
>   and a location field containing geographic information such as
>   latitude, longitude, country, and other fields (fields will vary based
>   on geography and availability of information)

Looks like you **can** post latitude and longitude...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know that as message can include a place, but I don't want to post a message, I'm using the photo endpoint.

Comment: just appended those parameters

Comment: @Aaron - are you having troubles implementing this?  I have not tried myself, but it is still detailed in the documentation..

Comment: Why don't you post a new question and see if someone with a little more experience can shed some light on this. :)